# cordova platform add android launches android in different window

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I am trying to create my first android project using cordova on my Windows 7 machine. I have installed latest Android SDK and cordova. I have set path for ANDROID_PATH, ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS, ANDROID_TOOLS and ANT_HOME. 
Using directions from http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface I have created the "hello" project but as I try to add android platform using:

```
cordova platform add android
```

from my command prompt android emulator opens up showing android home screen, so I can navigate through the OS but soon as close it I get the output:

```
C:\devCenter\private\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.
at C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:173:19
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:7
at C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
at flush (C:\Users\think ahead\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.3\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\think ahead\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

C:\devCenter\private\hello>
```

There is no android directory created inside platforms in "hello" project. Can someone please help me in pointing what I am missing/doing wrong.

**EDIT:** 
I have updated SDK with API-19 but I still getting the same problem. Is there anything else I have to do?

Comment: It is clearly showing that you need to install Android SDK version 19. `Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
Hint: Run "android" from your command-line to open the SDK manager.`

Comment: I updated the SDK to API-19 yet I still get the same error, is there more I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Run the **SDK Manager.exe** from your **/android-sdk/** folder and make sure you install the
**SDK Platform** for **Android 4.4.2 (API 19)**. Once that is done you just rerun the cordova command.

Comment: thanks, i updated the SDK to API-19, but I still got the same problem. After executing the command "cordova platform add android", android emulator opens up and no project is created and on closure of the emulator I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

From folder ADT-x86 (your SDK) run SDK manager.exe, then you search Android 4.4.2 (API 19).  check it! and you press install, before that you need to accept license agreement first, it was help me to solve that matter, hope this help :)